# Custom Auditing vs Custom Logging - SSIS

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, business-intelligence, audit-logging

Aren't they both the same?

I was reading [this article][1]

[1]: http://www.sqlmag.com/content1/topic/ssis-logging-and-data-auditing/catpath/business-intelligence-development-studio-bids/page/2 and I am still not clear about the difference between custom logging and auditing. They both seems to log events when the package runs...I haven't had much experience with this so if anyone who does/did this, can you clarify this for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes down to the type of information that you're capturing and there are many ways to do this in SSIS besides the examples provided in the article you cited. Logging is typically capturing information about package execution itself - errors encountered, execution time for the package or steps within the package, data flow buffer details, etc. Auditing is typically information about the data - how many records inserted, updated, and deleted; when it was done; what was the source; who ran the package; what machine did it run on, etc.

Comment: Thanks that makes things much clear for me now. As I understand from your post, Logging logs information about he package execution whereas auditing logs information about the data and it's flow.